# script tuning for include all computers in domain

Tags: powershell

I have a script which scans given computers in domain  for identifying and disables mobile hotspot function in windows 10. Script works properly , but i want to scan all my domain comupters, not only specified.. can anyone help me for adjusting this script?

```
$username = "domain\administrator"
$password = "Your password"
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $password
$computers = @("nr1", "nr2", "nr3")
foreach($computer in $computers){
    $hotspot = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -credential $credential -scriptblock {
    $hotspot = Get-Service "icssvc"
    if($hotspot.Status -eq "Running"){
        Write-Host "Hotspot is turned on on $computer" -ForegroundColor Red
        try{
            Stop-Service "icssvc"
            Write-Host "Successfully stopped service on $computer" -ForegroundColor Green
        }catch{
            Write-Host "Unable to stop service on $computer" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }else{
        Write-Host "No Hotspot running on $computer" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried to obtain all computers in a domain?

Comment: Have a look at [`Get-ADComputer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adcomputer)

Answer (score 1):

If you replace `$computers = @("nr1", "nr2", "nr3")` with something like:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Properties DNSHostName
```

That should return an array of hostnames. You may need to provide credentials via `-Credential`, and you can `-Filter` the results if you need to exclude any machines.

See docs and examples of `Get-ADComputer` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adcomputer?view=win10-ps).